# Actualizar el prefijo de un campo

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, db2

Necesito cambiar el prefijo de un campo por otro para todos los registros anteriores a una fecha.

```
UPDATE tabla
SET campo1 LIKE 'YYYYYYY%';
WHERE (campo1 LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX%' AND FECHA<DATE('2017-04-05'));
```

Aparece el siguiente informe de error:

```
Error SQL: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: LIKE;D 
SET ACT_GEOGRAFIA;=
```

¿Cómo sería la consulta correcta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes usar `LIKE` en la parte del `SET` de la query.

Puedes intentar utilizando [`REPLACE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_replace.html), función disponible en DB2:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET campo1 = REPLACE(campo1, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYY');
WHERE (campo1 LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX%' AND FECHA<DATE('2017-04-05'));
```

Comment: Y esto vale para encontrar una cadena concreta dentro de un campo? 
Quiero decir, en el campo pone YYYYYYY - 1234 y quiero cambiarlo a XXXXXXXXXXXXX - 1234. Gracias.

Comment: Si miras la documentación que te he enlazado, la funcion toma 3 argumentos de entrada: la columna, el texto que se busca y el texto por el que se sustitye.Asi que en el caso que pones, sería `REPLACE(columna, 'YYYYYYY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX')`